# Hibernate error when hbm2ddl.auto is update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScans(value = {
            @ComponentScan("org.kalifornia.fridgeapp.DAO"),
            @ComponentScan("org.kalifornia.fridgeapp.service")
            } )
@PropertySource("classpath:mysql.properties")
public class HibernateConfig {

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory()
{
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    try
    {
        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(restDataSource());
        factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(FridgeUser.class);
        factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(Community.class);
        factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(Container.class);
        factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(Item.class);
        factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(Product.class);

    } catch(IOException exception) {
        System.out.print(exception.fillInStackTrace());
        return null;
    }
    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
public DataSource restDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fridge");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("kaszanka");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

Properties hibernateProperties() {
    return new Properties() {
        {
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
            setProperty("show_sql", "true");
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        }
    };
}
}
```

I wrote that code from tutorial and it works now but when I try to change a `hbm2ddl.auto` from create to update I get this error:

> $Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'DAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in org.kalifornia.fridgeapp.spring.config.HibernateConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by BasicDataSource

Comment: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/45210-not-supported-by-basicdatasource-spring-2-5-3-hibernated-based-jpa-tomcat-6 try to use different DataSource

Answer (score 0):

According to your log `nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by BasicDataSource` seems like an issue with BasicDataSource, try changing it to DriverManagerDataSource because it may be the case that BasicDataSource doesn't support hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update